# Phone reboots while running program

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk, reboot

Any reason why my programs log show this?  Somehow my program freezes the whole OS and no key or touchscreen input works.  When I plug into USB and try to use DDMS to see what the issue is I see this usually and then the phone reboots by itself.

```
11-28 18:42:43.418: I/ActivityThread(12904): Removing dead content provider: settings
11-28 18:42:43.428: E/JavaBinder(23580): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
11-28 18:42:43.438: I/ServiceManager(52): service 'backup' died
```

I know my program is the culprit as that is the only ap that seems to work as it spits out regular messages.  I am doing some pretty heavy lifting with Bluetooth SPP connection and then real time graphing along with math calculations using NDK. Can't seem to get to '/data/anr/traces.txt' as DDMS won't list anything in '/data'.  Any ideas on how I can find out what the crash is?

Hardware/Software used:  Can get this on same error on a Emulator 2.2 or a MyTouch 3G.   Using latest NDK rev.  Targeting Android 2.2 due to Bluetooth.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "heavy lifting" bit?  Using `ContentProvider`s with the NDK seems like a scary idea...  Do you have any idea what code might be causing this issue?

Comment: I'm reading in bluetooth data via SPP and then graphing certain data bits at sample rates of 256/sec, then I am taking that data writing it to file at about 9k bytes per sec, also doing some Gaussian FIR/IIR and FFT filters on the data and then generating data using custom C files via JNI and the NDK.  This then triggers listeners on the GUI to update with the new calculated values.  So yes aot of threading and heavy lifting...lol

Comment: Perhaps try encapsulating your NDK code within a Java thread, rather than managing threads natively?  That is, an Android `Thread` or `ASyncTask`

Comment: NDK calls are actually in their own Android Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you've managed to invoke a kernel panic, jolly well done! :)

The thing to do now is comment out bits of your program until it can run without rebooting the phone via a kernel panic, or crashing natively. Then comment things back *in* until you find the exact line(s) that indirectly causes the fault.

Comment: Oooh jolly fun finding this error, what do you think would be the most likely cause of this, in your best 'guesstimate'?  Bluetooth, Real time graph or NDK math?

Comment: NDK is about the only thing that could cause a kernel panic.  Almost any java error would cause an ANR error, not a kernel panic :)

Comment: My guess - and it is only a guess - is that it's a bug in the Bluetooth driver. It'd be helpful if you supplied the hardware you are using, and the OS & kernel version information.